How does the Eurostar have an order of magnitude lower carbon footprint than UK national rail?
World in Data has a graphic on carbon footprint by travel mode.  It reports that National Rail has a footprint of 35g per passeger kikometer (PK), while the Eurostar, a train that goes from London to Paris/Brussels, has a footprint of 4g/PK.
The graphic references the UK government Greenhouse gas reporting: conversion factors 2022 which discusses the methodology in sections 5.66 - 5.70 but does not try and explain the differences.
What is the reason(s) for this massive difference?


I would assume that the National Rail figure is an average that includes diesel as well as electric services, and includes local trains with a more stop-start duty cycles that would likely have a much higher carbon footprint than services like Eurostar that stop infrequently. I would expect that the best case for National Rail would be similar to Eurostar, but the average is inflated by some trains with much higher carbon footprint.
Eurostar state that their electricity is 40% wind in the UK (https://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/sustainability). I don't know of any specific claims for UK national rail operators.

This rail factsheet says only 38% of our total railway routing is electrified, so we do still need a lot of diesels.

Also one uses high speed tracks: better signalling, less slow down or stops (btw where electric trains also are better). In general: electric generators are much more efficient compared diesel engines (less problem on weight and space, and usually they are operated at optimal power/speed (operator shut down entire generator in case of low demand)

In 2023 in the United Kingdom, only 37% of the railway network is electrified (by comparison, this is 56% in the EU, 58% in France, and 100% in Switzerland).  The rest of the network runs on diesel.  By comparison, Eurostar is 100% electrified.  Electric engines are much more efficient than internal combustion engines, and fossil fuels make up 40% of electricity production in the UK and 8% in France.  If the engine is three times more efficient (electric vs. ICE) and 75% of the energy source is low-carbon, then a factor 9–12 lower carbon footprint is unsurprising.
This back-of-the-envelope estimate makes some shortcuts, as the busy parts of the network are more likely to be electrified than the quiet parts, and we don't know if the electricity purchased by Eurostar or other operators has the same carbon mix as the national grid average, but as a first rough estimate it works out.
